# Copying fields from a form on a webpage to another form on the same webpage using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am new to jQuery and I am working on adding a "Copy from above" button to a form. There are 10 sections of the form, each section has 9 fields.  I need to find a way to copy the data from "section 1, all 9 fields", into the fields in "section 2".  I have created the button and can get it to copy the top field, but I need to find a way to cycle through each field of the form and copy all of that data into the next section of the form. Please let me know what else I can provide/clarify or what sections of the HTML code would be helpful, as it is pretty vast. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function(){

        // Wrap every 7 elements in div, skipping first
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        var frm_top_container = $('#frm_field_632_container');
        var div;
        var idClass = 0;
        $('div:not(:first-of-type)', frm_top_container).each(function(i, e){
            if (i % 7 == 0) div =
            //add class to wrapper element
            $('<div/>').addClass('section id-'+idClass).appendTo(frm_top_container);
                div.append(e);
                //increment variable
                idClass++;
        });


        // Adding 'copy from above' button to bottom of each new section class
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $('div.section').append('<label>Copy from above</label><input type="checkbox" id="copy_from_above">');


        // Log the element's value
        //////////////////////////
        $('.section').each(function() {
            //set variable selector for both input and select elements ('*' is a wildcard)
            var allElements = $('div > *');
            //listen for any change of an input or select
            $(allElements).change(function(){
                //log the value in the console
                console.log($(this).val());
            });
        });


        // Create event listener for button click
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        $('#copy_from_above').on('click', function() {
            //if the button state is checked
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                //assign the value
                $("#field_azebfk").val( $("#field_ebwkv8").val());
            }
            else {
                //remove the value
                $("#field_azebfk").val("")
            }
        });

    }); //end

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="frm_field_632_container" class="frm_form_field frm_section_heading form-field  start-left">
<h3 class="frm_pos_top">START/END</h3>

<div id="frm_field_4741_container" class="frm_form_field  form-field"><a id="start-left-clear">Clear All</a></div>
<div id="frm_field_633_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_first_fifth">
    <label for="field_ebwkv8" class="frm_primary_label">Start Date 1
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="field_ebwkv8" name="item_meta[633]" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" class="auto_width frm_date hasDatepicker">



</div>
<div id="frm_field_634_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_fifth">
    <label for="field_sz8y0c" class="frm_primary_label">Start Time 1
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <select name="item_meta[634]" id="field_sz8y0c" class="auto_width">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
            <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
            <option value="01:00 AM">01:00 AM</option>
            <option value="01:30 AM">01:30 AM</option>
            <option value="02:00 AM">02:00 AM</option>
            <option value="02:30 AM">02:30 AM</option>
            <option value="03:00 AM">03:00 AM</option>
            <option value="03:30 AM">03:30 AM</option>
            <option value="04:00 AM">04:00 AM</option>
            <option value="04:30 AM">04:30 AM</option>
            <option value="05:00 AM">05:00 AM</option>
            <option value="05:30 AM">05:30 AM</option>
            <option value="06:00 AM">06:00 AM</option>
            <option value="06:30 AM">06:30 AM</option>
            <option value="07:00 AM">07:00 AM</option>
            <option value="07:30 AM">07:30 AM</option>
            <option value="08:00 AM">08:00 AM</option>
            <option value="08:30 AM">08:30 AM</option>
            <option value="09:00 AM">09:00 AM</option>
            <option value="09:30 AM">09:30 AM</option>
            <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
            <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
            <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
            <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
            <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
            <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
            <option value="01:00 PM">01:00 PM</option>
            <option value="01:30 PM">01:30 PM</option>
            <option value="02:00 PM">02:00 PM</option>
            <option value="02:30 PM">02:30 PM</option>
            <option value="03:00 PM">03:00 PM</option>
            <option value="03:30 PM">03:30 PM</option>
            <option value="04:00 PM">04:00 PM</option>
            <option value="04:30 PM">04:30 PM</option>
            <option value="05:00 PM">05:00 PM</option>
            <option value="05:30 PM">05:30 PM</option>
            <option value="06:00 PM">06:00 PM</option>
            <option value="06:30 PM">06:30 PM</option>
            <option value="07:00 PM">07:00 PM</option>
            <option value="07:30 PM">07:30 PM</option>
            <option value="08:00 PM">08:00 PM</option>
            <option value="08:30 PM">08:30 PM</option>
            <option value="09:00 PM">09:00 PM</option>
            <option value="09:30 PM">09:30 PM</option>
            <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
            <option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
            <option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
            <option value="11:30 PM">11:30 PM</option>
    </select>



</div>
<div id="frm_field_635_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_fifth">
    <label for="field_cu4pnx" class="frm_primary_label">End Time 1
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <select name="item_meta[635]" id="field_cu4pnx" class="auto_width">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
            <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
            <option value="01:00 AM">01:00 AM</option>
            <option value="01:30 AM">01:30 AM</option>
            <option value="02:00 AM">02:00 AM</option>
            <option value="02:30 AM">02:30 AM</option>
            <option value="03:00 AM">03:00 AM</option>
            <option value="03:30 AM">03:30 AM</option>
            <option value="04:00 AM">04:00 AM</option>
            <option value="04:30 AM">04:30 AM</option>
            <option value="05:00 AM">05:00 AM</option>
            <option value="05:30 AM">05:30 AM</option>
            <option value="06:00 AM">06:00 AM</option>
            <option value="06:30 AM">06:30 AM</option>
            <option value="07:00 AM">07:00 AM</option>
            <option value="07:30 AM">07:30 AM</option>
            <option value="08:00 AM">08:00 AM</option>
            <option value="08:30 AM">08:30 AM</option>
            <option value="09:00 AM">09:00 AM</option>
            <option value="09:30 AM">09:30 AM</option>
            <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
            <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
            <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
            <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
            <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
            <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
            <option value="01:00 PM">01:00 PM</option>
            <option value="01:30 PM">01:30 PM</option>
            <option value="02:00 PM">02:00 PM</option>
            <option value="02:30 PM">02:30 PM</option>
            <option value="03:00 PM">03:00 PM</option>
            <option value="03:30 PM">03:30 PM</option>
            <option value="04:00 PM">04:00 PM</option>
            <option value="04:30 PM">04:30 PM</option>
            <option value="05:00 PM">05:00 PM</option>
            <option value="05:30 PM">05:30 PM</option>
            <option value="06:00 PM">06:00 PM</option>
            <option value="06:30 PM">06:30 PM</option>
            <option value="07:00 PM">07:00 PM</option>
            <option value="07:30 PM">07:30 PM</option>
            <option value="08:00 PM">08:00 PM</option>
            <option value="08:30 PM">08:30 PM</option>
            <option value="09:00 PM">09:00 PM</option>
            <option value="09:30 PM">09:30 PM</option>
            <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
            <option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
            <option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
            <option value="11:30 PM">11:30 PM</option>
    </select>



</div>
<div id="frm_field_636_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_fifth">
    <label for="field_dxfgfn" class="frm_primary_label">End Date 1
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="field_dxfgfn" name="item_meta[636]" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" class="auto_width frm_date hasDatepicker">



</div>
<div id="frm_field_4619_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_last_fifth">
    <label class="frm_primary_label">T/O 1
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="frm_opt_container"><div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_4619-0"><label for="field_4619-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[4619][]" id="field_4619-0" value="T/O"> T/O</label></div>
</div>


</div>
<div id="frm_field_4695_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_first_half">
    <label for="field_zbkmdh" class="frm_primary_label">Shift Type 1
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>

<select name="item_meta[4695]" id="field_zbkmdh">
<option value="--Choose one--" selected="selected">--Choose one--</option>
    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
    <option value="Day">Day</option>
    <option value="Night">Night</option>
    <option value="Swing">Swing</option>
    <option value="Weekend Call">Weekend Call</option>
    </select>



</div>
<div id="frm_field_4696_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_last_half">
    <label class="frm_primary_label">If Cancelled 1
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="frm_opt_container"><div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_4696-0"><label for="field_4696-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[4696][]" id="field_4696-0" value="Cancelled"> Cancelled</label></div>
</div>


</div>
<div id="frm_field_637_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_first_fifth">
    <label for="field_azebfk" class="frm_primary_label">Start Date 2
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="field_azebfk" name="item_meta[637]" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" class="auto_width frm_date">



</div>
<div id="frm_field_638_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_fifth">
    <label for="field_hfnidx" class="frm_primary_label">Start Time 2
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <select name="item_meta[638]" id="field_hfnidx" class="auto_width">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
            <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
            <option value="01:00 AM">01:00 AM</option>
            <option value="01:30 AM">01:30 AM</option>
            <option value="02:00 AM">02:00 AM</option>
            <option value="02:30 AM">02:30 AM</option>
            <option value="03:00 AM">03:00 AM</option>
            <option value="03:30 AM">03:30 AM</option>
            <option value="04:00 AM">04:00 AM</option>
            <option value="04:30 AM">04:30 AM</option>
            <option value="05:00 AM">05:00 AM</option>
            <option value="05:30 AM">05:30 AM</option>
            <option value="06:00 AM">06:00 AM</option>
            <option value="06:30 AM">06:30 AM</option>
            <option value="07:00 AM">07:00 AM</option>
            <option value="07:30 AM">07:30 AM</option>
            <option value="08:00 AM">08:00 AM</option>
            <option value="08:30 AM">08:30 AM</option>
            <option value="09:00 AM">09:00 AM</option>
            <option value="09:30 AM">09:30 AM</option>
            <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
            <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
            <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
            <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
            <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
            <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
            <option value="01:00 PM">01:00 PM</option>
            <option value="01:30 PM">01:30 PM</option>
            <option value="02:00 PM">02:00 PM</option>
            <option value="02:30 PM">02:30 PM</option>
            <option value="03:00 PM">03:00 PM</option>
            <option value="03:30 PM">03:30 PM</option>
            <option value="04:00 PM">04:00 PM</option>
            <option value="04:30 PM">04:30 PM</option>
            <option value="05:00 PM">05:00 PM</option>
            <option value="05:30 PM">05:30 PM</option>
            <option value="06:00 PM">06:00 PM</option>
            <option value="06:30 PM">06:30 PM</option>
            <option value="07:00 PM">07:00 PM</option>
            <option value="07:30 PM">07:30 PM</option>
            <option value="08:00 PM">08:00 PM</option>
            <option value="08:30 PM">08:30 PM</option>
            <option value="09:00 PM">09:00 PM</option>
            <option value="09:30 PM">09:30 PM</option>
            <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
            <option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
            <option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
            <option value="11:30 PM">11:30 PM</option>
    </select>



</div>
<div id="frm_field_639_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_fifth">
    <label for="field_cftv7y" class="frm_primary_label">End Time 2
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <select name="item_meta[639]" id="field_cftv7y" class="auto_width">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
            <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
            <option value="01:00 AM">01:00 AM</option>
            <option value="01:30 AM">01:30 AM</option>
            <option value="02:00 AM">02:00 AM</option>
            <option value="02:30 AM">02:30 AM</option>
            <option value="03:00 AM">03:00 AM</option>
            <option value="03:30 AM">03:30 AM</option>
            <option value="04:00 AM">04:00 AM</option>
            <option value="04:30 AM">04:30 AM</option>
            <option value="05:00 AM">05:00 AM</option>
            <option value="05:30 AM">05:30 AM</option>
            <option value="06:00 AM">06:00 AM</option>
            <option value="06:30 AM">06:30 AM</option>
            <option value="07:00 AM">07:00 AM</option>
            <option value="07:30 AM">07:30 AM</option>
            <option value="08:00 AM">08:00 AM</option>
            <option value="08:30 AM">08:30 AM</option>
            <option value="09:00 AM">09:00 AM</option>
            <option value="09:30 AM">09:30 AM</option>
            <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
            <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
            <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
            <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
            <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
            <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
            <option value="01:00 PM">01:00 PM</option>
            <option value="01:30 PM">01:30 PM</option>
            <option value="02:00 PM">02:00 PM</option>
            <option value="02:30 PM">02:30 PM</option>
            <option value="03:00 PM">03:00 PM</option>
            <option value="03:30 PM">03:30 PM</option>
            <option value="04:00 PM">04:00 PM</option>
            <option value="04:30 PM">04:30 PM</option>
            <option value="05:00 PM">05:00 PM</option>
            <option value="05:30 PM">05:30 PM</option>
            <option value="06:00 PM">06:00 PM</option>
            <option value="06:30 PM">06:30 PM</option>
            <option value="07:00 PM">07:00 PM</option>
            <option value="07:30 PM">07:30 PM</option>
            <option value="08:00 PM">08:00 PM</option>
            <option value="08:30 PM">08:30 PM</option>
            <option value="09:00 PM">09:00 PM</option>
            <option value="09:30 PM">09:30 PM</option>
            <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
            <option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
            <option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
            <option value="11:30 PM">11:30 PM</option>
    </select>



</div>
<div id="frm_field_640_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_fifth">
    <label for="field_5o29ta" class="frm_primary_label">End Date 2
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="field_5o29ta" name="item_meta[640]" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" class="auto_width frm_date">



</div>
<div id="frm_field_4620_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_last_fifth">
    <label class="frm_primary_label">T/O 2
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="frm_opt_container"><div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_4620-0"><label for="field_4620-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[4620][]" id="field_4620-0" value="T/O"> T/O</label></div>
</div>


</div>
<div id="frm_field_4697_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_first_half">
    <label for="field_etflnw" class="frm_primary_label">Shift Type 2
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>

<select name="item_meta[4697]" id="field_etflnw">
<option value="--Choose One--" selected="selected">--Choose One--</option>
    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
    <option value="Day">Day</option>
    <option value="Night">Night</option>
    <option value="Swing">Swing</option>
    <option value="Weekend Call">Weekend Call</option>
    </select>



</div>
<div id="frm_field_4698_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_last_half">
    <label class="frm_primary_label">If Cancelled 2
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="frm_opt_container"><div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_4698-0"><label for="field_4698-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[4698][]" id="field_4698-0" value="Cancelled"> Cancelled</label></div>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example, including your HTML.

Comment: I added the html that corresponds to the first form sections. There are a total of 20 individual sections, each field has a different id.

Comment: I have a fiddle with similar requirements, but a different html structure. Maybe it will help. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqrlking/8y4ugvz4/)

Comment: Thanks!! I finally figured this out!!